# How to retrieve last year data on line-by-line basis (main set grouped by year, month & aggregated on volume)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is there a way to easily retrieve last years data during volume aggregation, grouped by year, month.

Sample of code below (from BQ). It shows an error in the subquery
`WHERE clause expression references t1.date` which is neither grouped nor aggregated

```sql
SELECT
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t1.date) AS year,
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t1.date) AS month,
t1.ProductId AS product,
SUM(t1.Quantity) AS UnitsSold_TY,
(SELECT
    SUM(Quantity)
FROM `new-project-jun21.sales.sales_info`
WHERE
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date) =  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t1.date) - 1 AND
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t1.date) AND
    ProductId = t1.ProductId
GROUP BY
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date),
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date),
    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t1.date),
    ProductId) AS UnitsSold_LY
FROM `new-project-jun21.sales.sales_info` AS t1 
GROUP BY
year,
month,
product
ORDER BY product, year, month
```

Comment: This is correlated behavior, where the `t1.date` reference is in the `SELECT list` of the outer query expression. That means `t1.date` needs to be functionally dependent on the outer `GROUP BY` terms.  You could use `MAX(t1.date)`, but that really depends on the requirement of the query.  The requirement isn't clear.

Comment: Having said that, this appears to be a limitation of your database, which does not recognize that `year` and `month` in the outer `GROUP BY` terms resolve your expressions in the subquery.  You may need to explicitly factor out that logic so the database understands the dependence.  You could try to refer to `year` and `month` directly.  But most databases require those expressions be handled in a derived table or prior WITH clause term (CTE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have data every month, then you can use `lag()`.  I would recommend using `date_trunc()` instead of separating the year and date components.  So:

```
SELECT productId,
       DATE_TRUNC(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as yyyymm
       SUM(Quantity),
       LAG(SUM(Quantity), 12) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId ORDER BY MIN(date)) as yoy
FROM `new-project-jun21.sales.sales_info`
GROUP BY product_id, DATE_TRUNC(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
ORDER BY product, yyyymm;
```

If you have missing months for some products, then you can still use window functions, but the logic is a bit more complicated.

EDIT:

If you don't have data every month, then you can use a `RANGE` specification, but you need a month counter:

```
SELECT productId,
       DATE_TRUNC(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH) as yyyymm
       SUM(Quantity),
       MAX(SUM(Quantity)) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductId
                                ORDER BY DATE_DIFF(MIN(DATE), DATE '2000-01-01', month)
                                RANGE BETWEEN 12 PRECEDING AND 12 PRECEDING
                               ) as yoy
FROM `new-project-jun21.sales.sales_info`
GROUP BY product_id, DATE_TRUNC(date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
ORDER BY product, yyyymm;
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Elegant & short code; but data not every month.

Comment: @VolodymyrMazur . . . I added the logic for that.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon for knowledge sharing / very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, this should be equivalent, but I'd probably try to avoid the correlated subquery:

```
WITH xrows AS (
      SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM t1.date)  AS year
           , EXTRACT(MONTH FROM t1.date) AS month
           , t1.ProductId AS product
           , SUM(t1.Quantity) AS UnitsSold_TY
        FROM `new-project-jun21.sales.sales_info` AS t1 
       GROUP BY year, month, product
     )
SELECT t.*
     , ( SELECT SUM(Quantity)
           FROM `new-project-jun21.sales.sales_info`
          WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date)  = t.year - 1
            AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date) = t.month
            AND ProductId = t.ProductId
       ) AS UnitsSold_LY
  FROM xrows t
 ORDER BY product, year, month
;
```

Adjusted to remove the unnecessary `GROUP BY` in the correlated subquery.

Comment: Thank you Jon. Working well! Read through CTE as well to improve my beginner knowledge.